# How to extend ListItem to be able to have childs inside BulletList

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using asp.net C#.
I have BulletList, and I would like to add ListItem that will render with childs.
That is, inside every `<li>` I can add more controls to be rendered.

How can I achieve that?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why BulletedList has a collection of ListItems. ListItems are generally used for form elements (thus the Selected, Value, Text properties) and doesn't make sense to be used for bulleted lists. There is also no property which contains child ListItems for you to accomplish your goal. I would suggest using your own classes to do this. Here is a quick mockup:

```
public static class BulletList
{
    public static string RenderList(List<BulletListItem> list) {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (list != null && list.Count > 0)
        {
            sb.Append("<ul>");
            foreach(var item in list) {
                sb.Append(item.Content);
                sb.Append(BulletList.RenderList(item.Children));
            }
            sb.Append("</ul>");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public class BulletListItem
{ 
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public List<BulletListItem> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create your list with children and output it...

```
var items = new List<BulletListItem>();
items.Add(new BulletListItem() { Content = "Root 1" });
items.Add(new BulletListItem() { Content = "Root 2", Children = new List<BulletListItem>() { new BulletListItem() { Content = "Child 2.1" }} });
items.Add(new BulletListItem() { Content = "Root 3" });
Response.Write(BulletList.RenderList(items));
```

Comment: isn't inheriting from WebControl neccesary? shouldn't do control?

Comment: Using a web control depends on what you want to accomplish. for instance if you want to maintain state between postbacks, which is the primary purpose for web controls then you could convert this to fit that model. For simply outputting a list, which doesn't need to maintain state, it's easier to just output the html. If you need to do postbacks on the page I would suggest using ajax and returning json/only the data you need and manipulating the page content through javascript. You could also use updatePanels but it's up to what you're most comfortable with.